# NetworkManager's strategy in picking a Wifi network

Tags: wifi, network-interface, networkmanager

When several configured WiFi networks are available, it seems that NetworkManager does not always pick the one with the strongest signal.

How does NetworkManager choose the preferred WiFi and is it possible to configure or implement different strategies?

Comment: I seem to notice it picking the last network it was connected to, even though the signal is the weakest among all the saved networks in range.  Very annoying.